# SpringCloudStream with Confuent schema registry

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I'm new to Spring Cloud Stream and I'm trying to figure out how to make a Kafka binder work with the econfluent schema registry,
I have read the documentation and it looks somehow deprecated, and the latest version of Spring Cloud Stream states that developers should use functional programming and all examples show the use of EnableSchemaRegistryClient annotation (which is now deprecated). Basically, I want to use the confluent schema registry (running on default port 8081) and add the schema id to the Avro-generated object that I want to persist in my Kafka topic (running on default port 9092).

As far as I know, to make Kafka work with the schema registry, I have to define a schema.registry.url under spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration (even though I only want to make my processor2 function produce avro objects instead of all my binders)
and also I have to define the Serde (in this case I want to use Confluent Serde), and apparently, that would be it, however, I'm not being successful in making it work,
I'm getting an error 'Missing required configuration "schema.registry.url" which has no default value'.

This is what I got so far

My YAML file

```
spring.cloud.function.definition: process1,process2 
   spring:
      cloud:
        stream:
          bindings:
            process1-out-0:
              destination: someStream
            process2-in-0:
              destination: streamIWantToConvertToAvro
            process2-out-0:
             destination: mySchemaRegistryStream
             producer:
               use-native-encoding: true
          kafka:
            binder:
              brokers: localhost:9092
              configuration:
                schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
                value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            bindings:
              process2-out-0:
                producer:
                  configuration:
                    schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081
                    value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
                    key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
```

Configuration class

```
//This should be doing the serialization internally, so my GeneratedAvroObejct (which is a POJO generated by Avro maven plugin using a defined schema) 
//transform into a real Avro Object
@Bean
public Serde<GeneratedAvroPOJO> avroInSerde() {
    final SpecificAvroSerde<GeneratedAvroPOJO> avroInSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
    return avroInSerde;
}

//This function should return my avro serialized object so it can be persisted into a Kafka topic
@Bean
public Function<KStream<String,SomeObject>, KStream<String,GeneratedAvroPOJO>> process2() {
    return (stream) -> stream.map(key, mySomeObject) -> {
        GeneratedAvroPOJO avroPojo = someClass.getAvroPojo();
        return KeyValue.pair(key, avroPojo);
}
```

I tried to follow this [example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-avro) to adapt it to my needs, but I have had no luck so far

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you're missing `avroInSerde.configure(...)` to pass in the registry there

Comment: I got rid of the error by setting spring.cloud.streams.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url: http://localhost:8081, however I'm not sure how SCS can tell what version of the schema registry to use, should I define it in the first parameter of the avroInSerde.configure() or should I define it in the yaml file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean "which version", but I believe you can cross-reference properties, so define the registry at the top-level as `schema-registry: http://...`, then use `${schema-registry}` everywhere else